# Goolge Signin stuck on loading page

Tags: google-signin

Some users stuck on loading when they use Google sign-in in recent day.
This issue seems to depend on the account because I use the same device and tried to use different accounts to sign-in, this issue only happened on a part of accounts.

Below is my setting:
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"

[image: example]

Below is my setting:
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"

I tried to downgrade play-services-auth version, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you request additional scopes like "/auth/youtube" or google drive?
I believe it tries to show you this warning https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en, so maybe you need to verify your app.

Answer (score 0):

Google says it is their bug and have corresponding issue filed in github
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/413

You need to pass the verification process for the youtube scope anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is from google's side but for now, remove the consent screen from the test state and publish it. **And It will work**